# Composer. Правильная генерация autoload.php файла

Tags: composer

Всем добрый день. Появилась вот какая проблема. Нужно из composer'ом выкачать 2 библиотеки:
PhpSpreadsheet и PHPWord.

Содержимое файла composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.28",
    "phpoffice/phpword": "^1.1"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Spreadsheet": "/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/",
      "PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\PhpWord": "/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.4"
    }
  }
}
```

Далее я вбиваю команду php composer.phar install, но мне выдаётся ошибка:

```
A non-empty PSR-4 prefix must end with a namespace separator.
```

И файл autoload.php не генерируется. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это лечится? И правильно ли я всё указал в опции psr-4 ?

Comment: В конце неймспейса должно быть `'\\'`. Но вообще зачем в там указывать библиотеки? Вы же не будете там свой код писать. Там же нет такого в [документации](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation) или где Вы такое видели?

Comment: Мне надо как то сделать так, чтобы после скачивания этих библиотек в папку vendor в этой же папке появился бы autoload.php. Чтобы я этот autoload.php у себя в проекте 1 раз подключил, и все классы, которые идут вместе с этими библиотеками сразу были бы доступны.
Чтобы мне вручную через require каждый файл отдельно не подключать.

Я думаю это давным давно уже стало стандартом

Comment: Я понимаю зачем автолоадинг и как он работает, мне не нужно это объяснять. Статей валом в интернете. Можете почитать [здесь](https://klisl.com/composer_autoload.html), [здесь](https://webformyself.com/avtozagruzka-klassov-s-composer-v-php/) или [здесь](https://github.com/codedokode/pasta/blob/master/php/autoload.md). Если коротко, то в `psr-4` Вам нужно указывать на директорию с соответствующим неймспейсом где Вы будете писать свой код (src или inc или app, как Вы там себе придумали), а не библиотеки. Посмотрите на файл `composer.json` в любом из PHP фреймворков.

Comment: Я Вам указывал на документацию, так как там нигде и слова нет чтобы засунуть библиотеку внтурь `"autoload": { "psr-4": { ... }}`.